Isotope issues with Wordpress gutenberg API Version 3
The Isotope Library was working correctly in my Gutenberg block under API version 2. However, after migrating to API version 3, the library's functionality has been affected. This is due to the itemSelector option's limitation to CSS selectors. As API version 3 embeds block content in an iframe, the library cannot accurately identify the target items. The same was for the container element but it had been solved by using a reference for the container as it accepts dom element.
This issue already exists in apiversion 2 but in Tablet and Mobile views as the content will also work inside an iframe.
Code:
const isotope = useRef()
useEffect(() => {   
isotope.current = new Isotope('.filter-container', {   itemSelector: '.filter-item',   layoutMode: 'fitRows',   });   

// cleanup   

return () => isotope.current.destroy()   }, [])


Is there a way to solve this issue?
I've tried to select child elements and then pass them as a NodeList or array to itemSelector option but nothing works. Even by using another methods of isotope such as appended, insert, or AddItems.

Can you expand more on how you're implementing Isotope.js? Are you using it in a custom block or as part of the editor, etc?

@EmielZuurbier I am trying to use it to build a custom block such as gallery

Okay. Are you trying to implement Isotope.js as a frontend view script?

@EmielZuurbier .. I am trying to implement it in the editor view.
